# Set XML API Headers

Tags: asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I am sening a XML POST request and I am sending my private and public api keys but receive a 401 error when sending request. I will attach the code and errors below. Any help on why I am receiving this error would be greatly appreciated.

```
<% 
Set xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xml.Open "POST", "https://sandbox.affirm.com/api/v2/charges", False
on error resume next
xml.setRequestHeader "public_api_key", "myPublicKey"
xml.setRequestHeader "private_api_key", "MyprivateKey"
xml.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
xml.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
xml.Send
Response.Write xml.responseText
Set xml = Nothing
%>
```

Error:

```
{"status_code": 401, "message": "You did not provide an API key pair.", "code": "api-key-pair-not-found", "type": "unauthorized"}
```

Comment: Have you read the [API Documentation](https://docs.affirm.com/affirm-developers/reference#authentication), that isn’t how it expects you to authenticate the API call. It uses an `Authorization` header to pass the keys, probably something like `Authorization: Basic {public_api_key}:{private_api_key}`. Both keys combined with a `:` should be base64 encoded.

Comment: @Lankymart I tried that and unfortunately  I am still receiving the same error. Maybe I am not formatting it properly? xml.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + "{Private}:{Public}"

Comment: Did you encode the `{Private}:{Public}` as a base64 encoded string though?

Comment: I don't recommend using `on error resume next`, especially when debugging

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, I think it was undeserved.  The OP has clearly done some research and tried something prior to asking a question

Comment: @John what research? Took me 2 mins to find the API documentation and point to the Authentication section which shows the use of `curl -u` which translates to basic authentication in HTTP. These are concepts that someone trying to consume a web API should already be aware of and we already have plenty of questions on [so] that deal with the exact issue. It should be flagged as a duplicate but I'm guessing you won't be doing that.

Comment: From your comments, it looks like you are not BASE64 encoding the keys after concatenating them.   Note, in the answer linked to as a duplicate they call them username & password, but it is the same otherwise.